# The commands linsolve or solve from sympy cannot solve a 1D linear equation

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, linear-algebra

I write my code below in order to introduce the problem:

```
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing()
import numpy as np
import math

n=2

u,v=sp.symbols('u v')
a,b,c,d,h=sp.symbols('a b c d h')
k=sp.symbols('k')

diffmatrix=sp.zeros(n)

for i in range(n):
    diffmatrix[i,i] = sp.symbols('D'+str(i+1))
    globals()['D'+str(i+1)]=sp.symbols('D'+str(i+1))

f=[]
var=[]

var.append('u')
var.append('v')

# f.append(u+v)
# f.append(u-v**2)

f.append(a-c*u+d*v+u**2*v)
f.append(b+h*u-d*v-u**2*v)

f=sp.Matrix(f)
var=sp.Matrix(var)

jacobianmat=f.jacobian(var)

phi=[]
alpha=[]
beta=[]
psi=[]
gamma=[]
for i in range(n):
    phi.append(sp.symbols('phi' + str(i)))
    alpha.append(sp.symbols('alpha' + str(i)))
    beta.append(sp.symbols('beta'+str(i)))
    psi.append(sp.symbols('psi' + str(i)))
    gamma.append(sp.symbols('gamma' + str(i)))
    globals()['phi' + str(i)] = sp.symbols('phi' + str(i))
    globals()['alpha' + str(i)] = sp.symbols('alpha' + str(i))
    globals()['beta' + str(i)] = sp.symbols('beta' + str(i))
    globals()['psi' + str(i)] = sp.symbols('psi' + str(i))
    globals()['gamma' + str(i)] = sp.symbols('gamma' + str(i))
    
auxiliarterm=sp.linsolve(sp.Matrix([np.dot((jacobianmat-(k**2)*diffmatrix)[0:n-1],phi[0:n-1])])+sp.Matrix(jacobianmat-(k**2)*diffmatrix)[0:n-1,n-1],phi[0:n-1])

phi[0:n-1]=sp.Matrix(list(auxiliarterm))
phi[n-1]=1

doublesummationsecondorder=[]
for functionnumber in range(n):
    tempsum=0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            tempsum=sp.Add(tempsum,phi[i]*phi[j]*sp.diff(f[functionnumber],var[i],var[j]))
    tempsum=-tempsum/4
    doublesummationsecondorder.append(tempsum)

doublesummationsecondorder=sp.Matrix(doublesummationsecondorder)

alpha=sp.linsolve(sp.Matrix(np.dot(jacobianmat,alpha))-doublesummationsecondorder,alpha)

alpha=sp.Matrix(sp.Transpose(sp.Matrix(list(alpha))))

beta=sp.linsolve(sp.Matrix(np.dot(jacobianmat-4*k**2*diffmatrix,beta))-doublesummationsecondorder,beta)

beta=sp.Matrix(sp.Transpose(sp.Matrix(list(beta))))

doublesummationthirdorder1=[]
doublesummationthirdorder2=[]
triplesummationthirdorder=[]
for functionnumber in range(n):
    tempsum1=0
    tempsum2=0
    tempsum3=0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            tempsum1=sp.Add(tempsum1,phi[i]*(alpha[j]+beta[j]/2)*sp.diff(f[functionnumber],var[i],var[j]))
            tempsum2=sp.Add(tempsum2,phi[i]*beta[j]*sp.diff(f[functionnumber],var[i],var[j]))
            for l in range(n):
                tempsum3=sp.Add(tempsum3,phi[i]*phi[j]*phi[l]*sp.diff(f[functionnumber],var[i],var[j],var[l]))
    doublesummationthirdorder1.append(tempsum1)
    doublesummationthirdorder2.append(tempsum2)
    triplesummationthirdorder.append(tempsum3)
    
doublesummationthirdorder1=sp.Matrix(doublesummationthirdorder1)
doublesummationthirdorder2=sp.Matrix(doublesummationthirdorder2)
triplesummationthirdorder=sp.Matrix(triplesummationthirdorder)
    
auxiliarterm=sp.linsolve(sp.Matrix([np.dot((sp.matrices.Transpose(jacobianmat)-(k**2)*diffmatrix)[0:n-1],psi[0:n-1])])+sp.Matrix(sp.matrices.Transpose(jacobianmat)-(k**2)*diffmatrix)[0:n-1,n-1],psi[0:n-1])

psi[0:n-1]=sp.Matrix(list(auxiliarterm))
psi[n-1]=1

print('Almost ready')

auxiliarterm=sp.solve(sp.Matrix([np.dot((jacobianmat-(k**2)*diffmatrix)[0:n-1],gamma[0:n-1])])+sp.Matrix(doublesummationthirdorder1[0:n-1])+sp.Matrix(3/math.factorial(4)*sp.Matrix(triplesummationthirdorder[0:n-1])),gamma[0:n-1])
```

As you can see, as n=2, then the last equation that is being solved is a 1D (linear) equation. The problem is that, for some reason, I cannot get its solution. In any case, if I try with the other vector field given by f=[u+v,u-v^2], then everything works fine. I would like to know if this is a problem with the memory, the efficiency of the symbolic calculation or if there's a problem with my code.

Everything will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Oscar has pointed out, the expression is large and the solving gets bogged down in handling all the symbols. The following routine will simplify an expression to let you work with a small set of symbols:

```
def keepx(eq, x):
  """collapse non-x dependent Add and Mul into Duumy symbols
  and return e, r where e is the new expresion and r is
  the dictionary that can restore e: eq == e.xreplace(r)

  Examples
  ========

  >>> from sympy import solve, symbols
  >>> from sympy.abc import x
  >>> y = symbols('y', positive=True)
  >>> eq = 1/(3*x*y + 1) + 4*x*y + 5

  Dummy symbols with no name are used to keep track of the
  constants. The retain unique identity, however:

  >>> e, r = keepx(eq, x); e
  _ + _*x + 1/(_ + _*x)
  >>> assert e.xreplace(r) == eq
  >>> sol = solve(eq, x)
  >>> _sol = [i.xreplace(r).factor() for i in solve(e, x)]
  >>> assert sol == _sol
  """
  reps = {}
  def store(i):
      d = Dummy('')
      reps[d] = i
      return d
  def do(e):
    if e.is_Add or e.is_Mul:
        i, d = e.as_independent(x)
        if i is not e.identity:
            i = store(i)
            d = do(d)
            return e.func(i, d)
    if not e.args:
        return e
    return e.func(*[do(i) for i in e.args])
  return do(eq), reps
```

To use it in your case to get a solution just do the following:

```
>>> eq, x = (sp.Matrix([np.dot((jacobianmat-(k**2)*diffmatrix)[
0:n-1],gamma[0:n-1])])+sp.Matrix(doublesummationthirdorder1[0:n-
1])+sp.Matrix(3/math.factorial(4)*sp.Matrix(triplesummationthirdorder[0:n-
1])),gamma[0:n-1])
>>> e, r = keepx(eq, x)
>>> auxiliarterm = solve(e, x)[0].xreplace(r)
```

It's still an unwieldy expression, but now you have a fast solution to the problem (and a routine you can use whenever you have to mask off the "noise" to be able to work with the core of the expression).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the solvers will try to expand the expression that you have and these expressions become large when expanded so this is slow. Expansion is generally necessary for a system of linear equations for symbolic cancellation. In this case since it is only a single equation you can skip that step if you are sure that there is a unique solution:

```
In [41]: a = Wild('a')

In [42]: b = Wild('b')

In [43]: match = eq[0].match(a*s[0]+b)

In [44]: sol = -match[b]/match[a]

In [45]: sol
Out[45]: 
             ⎛                     2                      2                                                                                                 
    ⎛     2⎞ ⎜               2⋅D₁⋅k ⋅u + 2⋅c⋅u + d⋅v - 3⋅u ⋅v                                                                                               
2⋅u⋅⎝d + u ⎠⋅⎜───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── + ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
             ⎜    2  4           2         2          2                2  2     ⎛     3     8       3    6       3  6  2        2       6         2     6   
             ⎝2⋅D₁ ⋅k  + 4⋅D₁⋅c⋅k  - 8⋅D₁⋅k ⋅u⋅v + 2⋅c  - 8⋅c⋅u⋅v + 8⋅u ⋅v    2⋅⎝32⋅D₁ ⋅D₂⋅k  + 8⋅D₁ ⋅d⋅k  + 8⋅D₁ ⋅k ⋅u  + 72⋅D₁ ⋅D₂⋅c⋅k  - 144⋅D₁ ⋅D₂⋅k ⋅u⋅
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            

                                                                                                                   2    4         2  4  3              2    
                                                                                                               8⋅D₁ ⋅d⋅k ⋅u + 8⋅D₁ ⋅k ⋅u  + 10⋅D₁⋅c⋅d⋅k ⋅u +
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
         2      4        2    4  2       2      4        2    4           2    4  2        2  4  3               2  4                4                  4  2
v + 18⋅D₁ ⋅c⋅d⋅k  + 18⋅D₁ ⋅c⋅k ⋅u  - 2⋅D₁ ⋅d⋅h⋅k  - 32⋅D₁ ⋅d⋅k ⋅u⋅v - 2⋅D₁ ⋅h⋅k ⋅u  - 32⋅D₁ ⋅k ⋅u ⋅v + 48⋅D₁⋅D₂⋅c ⋅k  - 192⋅D₁⋅D₂⋅c⋅k ⋅u⋅v + 192⋅D₁⋅D₂⋅k ⋅u 
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            

          2  3         2  2               2             2  2             2  3          2  4        2          2  3      2                        2          
 10⋅D₁⋅c⋅k ⋅u  + 4⋅D₁⋅d ⋅k ⋅v - 2⋅D₁⋅d⋅h⋅k ⋅u - 8⋅D₁⋅d⋅k ⋅u ⋅v - 2⋅D₁⋅h⋅k ⋅u  - 12⋅D₁⋅k ⋅u ⋅v + 2⋅c ⋅d⋅u + 2⋅c ⋅u  + c⋅d ⋅v - 2⋅c⋅d⋅h⋅u - 2⋅c⋅d⋅u ⋅v - 2⋅c⋅h
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  2          2    2          2  2  2               2              2                 2  2            2  3               2                2  2  2           2 
⋅v  + 12⋅D₁⋅c ⋅d⋅k  + 12⋅D₁⋅c ⋅k ⋅u  - 4⋅D₁⋅c⋅d⋅h⋅k  - 40⋅D₁⋅c⋅d⋅k ⋅u⋅v - 4⋅D₁⋅c⋅h⋅k ⋅u  - 40⋅D₁⋅c⋅k ⋅u ⋅v + 8⋅D₁⋅d⋅h⋅k ⋅u⋅v + 32⋅D₁⋅d⋅k ⋅u ⋅v  + 8⋅D₁⋅h⋅k ⋅
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                   2                                                                                                                        
                               D₁⋅k  + c - 2⋅u⋅v                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            

  3        4      2              2          4                                                                                                               
⋅u  - 3⋅c⋅u ⋅v - d ⋅h⋅v + 2⋅d⋅h⋅u ⋅v + 3⋅h⋅u ⋅v                                                                                                             
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 3            2  4  2         3  2          2  2                2  2  2          2  3  3      3        3  2      2          2            2    2      2  3   
u ⋅v + 32⋅D₁⋅k ⋅u ⋅v  + 8⋅D₂⋅c ⋅k  - 48⋅D₂⋅c ⋅k ⋅u⋅v + 96⋅D₂⋅c⋅k ⋅u ⋅v  - 64⋅D₂⋅k ⋅u ⋅v  + 2⋅c ⋅d + 2⋅c ⋅u  - 2⋅c ⋅d⋅h - 8⋅c ⋅d⋅u⋅v - 2⋅c ⋅h⋅u  - 8⋅c ⋅u ⋅v 
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            

                                                                               ⎞                                                                            
                                                                               ⎟                                                                            
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────⎟                                                                            
                       2  2          3          4  2          2  2        4  2⎞⎟                                                                            
+ 8⋅c⋅d⋅h⋅u⋅v + 8⋅c⋅d⋅u ⋅v  + 8⋅c⋅h⋅u ⋅v + 8⋅c⋅u ⋅v  - 8⋅d⋅h⋅u ⋅v  - 8⋅h⋅u ⋅v ⎠⎠                                                                            
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── - ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                        3     8       3    6       3  6  2        2       6        2     6  
                                                                                   16⋅D₁ ⋅D₂⋅k  + 4⋅D₁ ⋅d⋅k  + 4⋅D₁ ⋅k ⋅u  + 36⋅D₁ ⋅D₂⋅c⋅k  - 72⋅D₁ ⋅D₂⋅k ⋅u
                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            

                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
         2      4       2    4  2     2      4        2    4         2    4  2        2  4  3               2  4               4                 4  2  2    
⋅v + 9⋅D₁ ⋅c⋅d⋅k  + 9⋅D₁ ⋅c⋅k ⋅u  - D₁ ⋅d⋅h⋅k  - 16⋅D₁ ⋅d⋅k ⋅u⋅v - D₁ ⋅h⋅k ⋅u  - 16⋅D₁ ⋅k ⋅u ⋅v + 24⋅D₁⋅D₂⋅c ⋅k  - 96⋅D₁⋅D₂⋅c⋅k ⋅u⋅v + 96⋅D₁⋅D₂⋅k ⋅u ⋅v  + 6
                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            

                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                  ⎛           4              4  3             2             2  3         2  2             2  2           2  4  ⎞                            
                u⋅⎝4⋅D₁⋅D₂⋅d⋅k ⋅u + 4⋅D₁⋅D₂⋅k ⋅u  + 4⋅D₂⋅c⋅d⋅k ⋅u + 4⋅D₂⋅c⋅k ⋅u  + 2⋅D₂⋅d ⋅k ⋅v - 4⋅D₂⋅d⋅k ⋅u ⋅v - 6⋅D₂⋅k ⋅u ⋅v⎠                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
     2    2         2  2  2               2              2                 2  2            2  3               2                2  2  2           2  3       
⋅D₁⋅c ⋅d⋅k  + 6⋅D₁⋅c ⋅k ⋅u  - 2⋅D₁⋅c⋅d⋅h⋅k  - 20⋅D₁⋅c⋅d⋅k ⋅u⋅v - 2⋅D₁⋅c⋅h⋅k ⋅u  - 20⋅D₁⋅c⋅k ⋅u ⋅v + 4⋅D₁⋅d⋅h⋅k ⋅u⋅v + 16⋅D₁⋅d⋅k ⋅u ⋅v  + 4⋅D₁⋅h⋅k ⋅u ⋅v + 16
                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                        2                                                                                                                   
                                  - D₁⋅k  - c + 2⋅u⋅v                                                                                                       

                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
     2  4  2         3  2          2  2                2  2  2          2  3  3    3      3  2    2          2          2    2      2  3                    
⋅D₁⋅k ⋅u ⋅v  + 4⋅D₂⋅c ⋅k  - 24⋅D₂⋅c ⋅k ⋅u⋅v + 48⋅D₂⋅c⋅k ⋅u ⋅v  - 32⋅D₂⋅k ⋅u ⋅v  + c ⋅d + c ⋅u  - c ⋅d⋅h - 4⋅c ⋅d⋅u⋅v - c ⋅h⋅u  - 4⋅c ⋅u ⋅v + 4⋅c⋅d⋅h⋅u⋅v + 4
                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            

                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── - ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
      2  2          3          4  2          2  2        4  2   ⎛    2            ⎞ ⎛     3     8       3    6       3  6  2        2       6        2     6
⋅c⋅d⋅u ⋅v  + 4⋅c⋅h⋅u ⋅v + 4⋅c⋅u ⋅v  - 4⋅d⋅h⋅u ⋅v  - 4⋅h⋅u ⋅v    ⎝D₁⋅k  + c - 2⋅u⋅v⎠⋅⎝16⋅D₁ ⋅D₂⋅k  + 4⋅D₁ ⋅d⋅k  + 4⋅D₁ ⋅k ⋅u  + 36⋅D₁ ⋅D₂⋅c⋅k  - 72⋅D₁ ⋅D₂⋅k 
                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            

                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
           2      4       2    4  2     2      4        2    4         2    4  2        2  4  3               2  4               4                 4  2  2  
⋅u⋅v + 9⋅D₁ ⋅c⋅d⋅k  + 9⋅D₁ ⋅c⋅k ⋅u  - D₁ ⋅d⋅h⋅k  - 16⋅D₁ ⋅d⋅k ⋅u⋅v - D₁ ⋅h⋅k ⋅u  - 16⋅D₁ ⋅k ⋅u ⋅v + 24⋅D₁⋅D₂⋅c ⋅k  - 96⋅D₁⋅D₂⋅c⋅k ⋅u⋅v + 96⋅D₁⋅D₂⋅k ⋅u ⋅v  +
                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            

                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
     ⎛     2⎞ ⎛           4              4  3             2             2  3         2  2             2  2           2  4  ⎞                                
   v⋅⎝d + u ⎠⋅⎝4⋅D₁⋅D₂⋅d⋅k ⋅u + 4⋅D₁⋅D₂⋅k ⋅u  + 4⋅D₂⋅c⋅d⋅k ⋅u + 4⋅D₂⋅c⋅k ⋅u  + 2⋅D₂⋅d ⋅k ⋅v - 4⋅D₂⋅d⋅k ⋅u ⋅v - 6⋅D₂⋅k ⋅u ⋅v⎠                                
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       2    2         2  2  2               2              2                 2  2            2  3               2                2  2  2           2  3     
 6⋅D₁⋅c ⋅d⋅k  + 6⋅D₁⋅c ⋅k ⋅u  - 2⋅D₁⋅c⋅d⋅h⋅k  - 20⋅D₁⋅c⋅d⋅k ⋅u⋅v - 2⋅D₁⋅c⋅h⋅k ⋅u  - 20⋅D₁⋅c⋅k ⋅u ⋅v + 4⋅D₁⋅d⋅h⋅k ⋅u⋅v + 16⋅D₁⋅d⋅k ⋅u ⋅v  + 4⋅D₁⋅h⋅k ⋅u ⋅v + 
                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            

                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       2  4  2         3  2          2  2                2  2  2          2  3  3    3      3  2    2          2          2    2      2  3                  
16⋅D₁⋅k ⋅u ⋅v  + 4⋅D₂⋅c ⋅k  - 24⋅D₂⋅c ⋅k ⋅u⋅v + 48⋅D₂⋅c⋅k ⋅u ⋅v  - 32⋅D₂⋅k ⋅u ⋅v  + c ⋅d + c ⋅u  - c ⋅d⋅h - 4⋅c ⋅d⋅u⋅v - c ⋅h⋅u  - 4⋅c ⋅u ⋅v + 4⋅c⋅d⋅h⋅u⋅v +
                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            

                                                                                       
                                                                                       
                                                                                   2   
                                                                           ⎛     2⎞    
                                                                      0.75⋅⎝d + u ⎠    
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── - ────────────────────
        2  2          3          4  2          2  2        4  2⎞                      2
 4⋅c⋅d⋅u ⋅v  + 4⋅c⋅h⋅u ⋅v + 4⋅c⋅u ⋅v  - 4⋅d⋅h⋅u ⋅v  - 4⋅h⋅u ⋅v ⎠   ⎛    2            ⎞ 
                                                                   ⎝D₁⋅k  + c - 2⋅u⋅v⎠ 
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Also note that there is a Float in there (`0.75`). I would make sure to use only rational numbers here because polynomial operations with floating point coefficients are not well defined.

Comment: There should be a flag for simplifying in `solve_linear`: it is the `expand_mul` that is taking all the time.